# Python on iPhone 6

Tags: python, ios, iphone-6

Would `import os, sys` work on an iPhone app using Python?

```
os.system("pwd")
```

Is there a way to manage pathways and look at an iPhone's directories and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using Python on iPhone through [Pythonista](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pythonista/id528579881?mt=8) or a similar app. It depends entirely on the implementation of the app itself if `os` module functionality is available.

That said, you can't access the full iPhone file system from an iPhone app, because each app is sandboxed and can only see its own files. You can read more about iOS file system access [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

There are Objective-C APIs to access e.g. photos, but it again depends on the Python implementation if they support them.